# After creating a top level category, the category itself is part of it

Tags: categories, servicenow

I recently created a new category which should appear on my page. This category should have 3 Items which should be as well displayed directly on the main page. But instead my category is shown on the top page, but I have to select it first to view my 3 Items in it.
[image: My Cat]

To show my 3 Items, I can click on either "Connectivity Management". 
It looks as if I had 2 Categories in each other, but that's not the case. I definitely have just one.
I had a look at the servicenow documentation about categories, but there was no hint about my problem.
I am using the FUJI release.
Any Idea how I can remove the bottom category?

I have other top level categories which work just as I wanted them, I compared both and found no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you adding this to your page and what type of page are you adding this to?

I've seem something similar happen when adding this to a *Homepage* such as the *ESS Homepage*. Is this what you are trying to do?

When selecting to add a **Catalog Category** to a home page you will have two options, **Category Details** and **Category Items**

If you choose *Category Details*, you see something similar to what you see.

[image]

If you instead choose *Category Items*, you will see the items within the category

[image]

Comment: Hey Kirk, yes that was indeed what I was looking for. I fixed it yesterday myself, but your answer is 100% what I did.